# Отправить текст и скриншот в разные сервисы на Android

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-intent

Есть *dialogFragment* в котором выводится результат теста. В нём есть кнопка *Поделиться*. Как добавить возможность по нажатию на эту кнопку отправлять в разные сервисы (соцсети, Вайбер и т.п.) сам скриншот этого *dialogFragment*, сопроводительный текст и ссылку на приложение в Google Play?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: Это слишком общий вопрос, тут целую программу писать надо и вряд ли кто то будет это делать для вас.

Comment: @pavlofff Думал может есть у кого то готовое решение.

Comment: @metalurgus это я сразу нашел, спасибо

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Делать скриншот с к-л `View` можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805831/3212712):

   ```
   public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
       Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
       Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
       v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
       v.draw(c);
       return b;
   }
   ```
2. Далее полученный `Bitmap` можно запихнуть в `Intent`, запускающий системный диалог шаринга один из этих способов (не вникал, но они, похоже, предлагают полученный `Bitmap` сначала записать в файл).

   Способ [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428494/3212712):

   ```
   String url = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), image, "title", null);
   ```

   Способ [два](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503928/3212712):

   ```
   File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
   File imageFile = new File(path, getCurrentTime()+ ".png");
   FileOutputStream fileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fileOutPutStream);

   fileOutPutStream.flush();
   fileOutPutStream.close();

   String url = "file://" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
   ```
3. Теперь формируем и запускаем `Intent` шаринга:

   ```
   final Intent intent = new Intent(     android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "ТУТ_КАКОЙ_ТО_ТЕКСТ");
   intent.setType("image/png");
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with Friends"));
   ```

**P.S.**

Возможно нельзя вот так просто передать и изображение и текст для всех сервисов. Отдельно текст и изображение так, можно передать. Но вот всякие твиттеры врятли будут принимать изображения. Для  корректной работы с шарингом в к-л конкретный сервсис лучше всего юзать их SDK

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, `-1` в данном случае это константа. то ли `match_parent` то ли `wrap_content`. Попробуйте просто `view.getHeight()`

Comment: да спасибо, как раз хотел написать, что нужно так было сделать, скриншот получил и отправляется, теперь дело за текстом с ссылкой

Comment: в вайбер передается фото, в почту фото и текст, а например в фейсбук ничего не пеедается

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, с ЛицоКнигой, судя по гуглу надо дело иметь чрез их SDK. Насколько мне известно стандартного для всех сервисов принятия разнородного контента для постинга не существует. Текст-то простой все принять должны, а что-то большее - будут везде свои нюансы.

Comment: Спасибо! Тогда остановимся на тексте с ссылкой!

Answer (score 3):

Столкнулся с той же необходимостью - отправить фото(точнее несколько) и описание к нему с приложения. И возникла та же проблема что и у Максима Фомичёва.

Как с этим боролся.

Способ отправки выбрал через `intent`, без использования `API` соцсетей, почтовиков и мессенджеров (назову их просто мессенджерами).

Тоесть, передаю данные через `Intent` и вызываю список приложений способных обрабатывать несколько типов данных (смотри ответ [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487028/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android/487055#487055)), в моем случае это изображения и текст.  Далее дело за пользователем и его выбором мессенджера.

Решил протестировать как отрабатывается отправка в разных мессенджерах.

Мессенджеров с обработкой одновременно обоих типов данных, оказалось намного меньше нежели тех, которые могут работать с текстом и картинками но порознь друг от друга.

Далее не все так красочно. Так как даже те мессенджеры, которые неявными интентами "заявляют", что имеют функционал для обработки одновременно нескольких типов данных, если и обрабатывают их то уж очень лихо по разному, и даже иногда никак.

У некоторых, редакторы текста, которые появляются рядом с отправляемой картинкой - не принимают автоматически текст который мы передавали вместе с картинкой в `intente`, и разве что ручками его вводить каждый раз или копипастить(тоже ручками).

*Не с целью рекламы или антирекламы, а лишь из-за того что они бесплатны и установлены у меня на телефоне, возьму для примера всем известные Viber, Skype, Hangouts и Gmail. Они хороши каждый по своему, но подходят ли они для моих задач.*

Бэкэндная часть моих исследований:

Несколько `uri` картинок заливал в `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
```

Далее, естественно, получив все нужные `permission`, вызываю:

```
private void openMultiDataSender() {
    String description = "some text";

    Intent sendMultiData = new Intent();
    sendMultiData.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    sendMultiData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
    sendMultiData.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, description);
    sendMultiData.setType("*/*");
    startActivity(sendMultiData);

}
```

Использование какого либо конкретного `MIME` типа не привело к желаемому результату, ровно как и попытки их комбинировать. Потому передаю `sendMultiData.setType("*/*");`.

Что имеем как результат передачи картинки и текста:

*`Skype`* - открывает редактор с пустым полем для добавления комментария и прикрепленными картинками.  Далее, если хотите - пишите ручками или вставляйте с буфера нужный вам текст, если вы его туда програмно добавили конечно.

*`Viber`* - открывает редактор с пустым полем для добавления комментария и прикрепленными картинками. Если картинка к передаче ОДНА - то отправится и картинка и текст который мы передавали. Если картинок много - отправятся только картинки.(кстати, максимум 10 картинок). Коментарии к картинкам как и у скайпа - пишем ручками.

*`Hangouts`* - открывает окно с кнопкой отправки и вложенными картинками. По нажатии на кнопку отправить - открывается окно чата и видим как картинки отправляются, и о чудо, неприметненько (если текста мало) в поле для ввода сообщения уже есть наш текст, нужно только нажать еще раз кнопку отправить. (Почему чудо, да потому что я его с 3-го раза его заметил, а перед этим просто закрывал чат и возвращался в начальное приложение). Но это все же лучше чем ничего.

*`Gmail`* - открывается редактор с залитым нашим текстом и картинками во вложениях.(ограничение только по сумарному весу картинок). Осталось выбрать адресата и отправить.

В процессе решения данной проблемы я рассматривал несколько вариантов выкрутиться с такой неудобной ситуации.

**Первый вариант.** Вызывать интенты последовательно, сначала с текстом, потом с картинкой(или наоборот). Но в таком случае есть риск  передать некомплектные данные.
Причиной тому:
1) Сложность получения подтверждения, что первая операция была успешна, перед тем как начать вторую. 
К примеру, пользователь перейдет в какой-то мессенджер, который нам неподвластен, а там просто откажется передавать данные.

2) Предположим, что первое действие все же было произведено и наша картинка или текст(смотря что первое отправляем) благополучно улетел адресату. И тем не менее, остается риск того, что пользователь может не подтвердить 2-е действие (не каждому по нраву за два захода отправлять какую то информацию, попробуйте убедить кого то что нужно именно 2 раза идти на почту чтобы отправить одну посылку).
В таком случае адресат рискует получить только первую часть того что мы собирались отправить.

Значит нужно писать всплывающие сообщения или диалоговые окна с инструкциями пользователю как отправить нужный нам набор данных. Трудоемкий и запутанный может получится код.

**Второй вариант:** Зная что картинки точно передаются, то можно сделать из нужного нам текста картинку и отправлять ее вместе с остальными картинками.

**Третий вариант:** Большинство мессенджеров поддерживает передачу *PDF* файлов. Как вариант можно сделать из текста и картинки/картинок один *PDF* файл. Ну или Другой текстовый документ поддерживающий изображения в теле. Но это довольно трудоемко и вряд ли займет меньше времени на кодинг нежели первый вариант со всеми диалоговыми окнами и повторными отправками данных.

Не могу пока предложить более оптимальных решений, к тому же предполагаю что есть уже какие то библиотеки готовые для отправки комбинированных данных, но мне они пока не известны, что хотел бы исправить.