# Создание кнопки "Поделиться" в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

Хочу сделать кнопку "Поделиться" в своем приложении, она будет предназначена для того, чтобы пользователь смог поделиться результатами пройденного уровня. Когда пользователь нажмет на "Поделиться" - всплывет список соц. сетей, куда он может кинуть свои результаты.

Например, нажал на "Поделиться" и выбрал "Вконтакте", после у него на стене вконтакте выкладываются результаты пройденного уровня. 
Я понимаю, тут, наверное, вам будет сложно объяснить, может поможете ссылкой на годный тутор?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как правку отменить, мы одновременно сделали :)

Comment: @pavel, э-э-э... Ну... Я хз) Думаю, пока её не приняли откатиться нельзя. Если примут - можно будет откатить её изменения. Ну или её не примут. Так что, думаю, надо просто подождать)

Comment: Юрий, я не понял в этой строчке откуда берется image: 

String url = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), image, "title", null);

В этом ответе 
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487028/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android

Comment: @user207012, это или путь к картинке или `Bitmap` смотрите в  [доках] http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage(android.content.ContentResolver, android.graphics.Bitmap, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)