# Создание одной картинки из TextView и ImageView

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-canvas

Добрый день. Необходимо реализовать метод добавления текста на изображение. Пользователю дается 10 картинок, а текст он может добавить абсолютно любой. Изначально пытался сделать через Canvas и возвращать изображение с уже добавленным текстом. Но тут получилась засада с многострочным текстом, который заранее неизвестен. Существует ли возможность объединить TextView с ImageView в одну картинку, чтобы потом сохранить в галерее с нанесенным текстом?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <TextView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Так вроде спрашивают как картинку получить, а не вьюшку.

Comment: Смогу ли я из FrameLayout сохранить изображение с нанесенным текстом в галерею?

Comment: @R1zen, да, можете. Вот тут описано как получить `Bitmap` из `View` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487055/17609

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вы - модератор? :О

Comment: @Flippy, ага) Уже неделю как)