# Передать несколько фотографий в WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, whatsapp

Я хочу отправить 2 фотографии из своего приложения в WhatsApp. У меня есть List из Uri, он передается в intent. Но ничего не отправляется, что я делаю не так? И возможно ли вообще отправлять несколько фотографий в другие приложения? Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.buttom);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri ur = Uri.parse("https://d2ph5fj80uercy.cloudfront.net/04/cat2972.jpg");
            ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<>();
            imageUris.add(ur); // Add your image URIs here
            imageUris.add(ur);

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847880/263405) ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны использовать Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE вместо Intent.ACTION_SEND.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
intent.setType("image/jpeg"); /* This example is sharing jpeg images. */

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for(String path : filesToSend /* список отправляемых файлов */) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    files.add(uri);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
startActivity(intent);
```

Это, можно упростить, но я оставил несколько строк, чтобы вы могли разбить каждый необходимый шаг.

Начиная с API 24, совместное использование файлов URI вызовет исключение FileUriExposedException. Чтобы исправить это, вы можете использовать URI контента с FileProvider.